# Cytoscape Edgehandles: multiple cy instances messing with Ghost Edgehandles

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js

I want to display several instances of cytoscape in a single page, in a time sequence: first one set of nodes are displayed on the graph, the user must create edges between them, then he moves to a second graph, etc.

There seems to be a conflict between my reinitialisation code and cy.edgehandles. In the first instance, everything works fine. From the second instance on, the "ghost" edges are not displayed while draging the edges.

I get the following error message in the console:

> jquery.cytoscape.js-edgehandles.js:333  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'id' of null jquery.cytoscape.js-edgehandles.js:333 
>   $.fn.cytoscapeEdgehandles.functions.init.drawLine
>   jquery.cytoscape.js-edgehandles.js:732 moveHandler
>   jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5 x.event.dispatchjquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
>   x.event.add.y.handle

The variable that appears to be "null" is :

> 333:  source: sourceNode.id(),

Here is the code I wrote to reinitialise the cy.instance:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
indexLevel++;// index to move from one instance to the next. 
cy.load(elesJson);// load nodes collection
cy.ready(); 
});
```

Here is my code:

//elements

```
$(function(){
var elesJson = { 
nodes: [{ data: { id: 'S'} }...],
edges: [{ data: { id: 'loan', source: 'B', target: 'U' } },...]};
```

// instance index

```
var indexLevel=0;
```

// cy initialisation

```
$("#cy"+indexLevel).cytoscape({
style: cytoscape.stylesheet()...
elements: elesJson, 
ready: function(){window.cy = this;cy.zoomingEnabled( false );
    cy.panningEnabled( false );});
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: Actually my initialization code is not the one I mentioned, but: $("#cy").cytoscape({ready: function(){                                                 window.cy = this; cy.zoomingEnabled( false );cy.panningEnabled( false );}); I have only one instance of cytoscape, which displays several graphs, depending on var indexLevel. But I need to reinitialize cy, for it to execute the code that displays the nodes on the graph. This reinitialisation  seems to conflict with "ghost edgehandler".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not what the issue is exactly, but I think the cause may be in the workflow.  It should be:

(1) `destroy()` the edgehandles on `cy`.

(2) `cy.destroy()` the core instance.

(3) Create a new core instance, `cy`.

(4) Create a new edgehandles on `cy`.

Alternate flow:

(1) Never destroy.

(2) Instead of destroying, empty graphs and re-use them: `cy.elements().remove()`

The alternate flow is probably safer if there is a bug in edgehandles, and it's certainly more efficient (i.e. faster).

If this doesn't solve the problem, then perhaps you could share some code (or send it to me privately if the code is sensitive) and we can post the generic results here.